# how to do ajax callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, lit-element

My scenario is , I have static data that is loaded in div, once after loaded I need to make ajax call and override the static data with new data, How to do the following in javascript

As I am newbie to lit-element, I dontknow how to do using callback function bit confused.
once the div is loaded I need to make ajax call and override the static data with new data. I got stuck please help or any alternatives

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js?module';
export class Example extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      staticobj: {type: Object}
   }
 }

constructor() {
    super();
   this.static=[{
     id: "value1",
     country: "TH",
     fee: 100   
   },{
    id:"value2",
    country: "SG",
    fee: 200
  }]
}

handleCall(id){
 $.ajax({
   url: "/en",
   method: 'get',
   global: false,
   async: false,
   data: {
     value: id
   },
   success: function (data) {
     callback(data, passData)
   }
 })
this.static=data; //override the static data
}

render(){
   this.static.map((e)=>{  
    return html`
   <div id="list">// call the ajax function once div loaded
     <p>${e.id}</p>
     <h6>${e.country}</h6>
     <h5>${e.fee}</h5>

  </div>
   `
   })
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get into the ES6 and LitElement mind set. Forget JQuery and use `fetch` (preferably with ES8 `async/await`). Fetch your data in LitElement's `firstUpdated()`. Then replace your array itself (the change won't be see if you replace the array elements themselves, because the change won't be rendered):

```
import { html, css, LitElement } from 'lit-element';

export default class FetchLit extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return css`
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    `;
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      users: { type: Array },
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.users = [
      {
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        email: 'jane.doe@somewhere.com',
      },
    ];
  }

  // Don't use connectedCallback() since it can't be async
  async firstUpdated() {
    await fetch(`https://demo.vaadin.com/demo-data/1.0/people?count=10`)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(async data => {
        this.users = data.result;
      });
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <ul>
        ${this.users.map(
          u =>
            html`
              <li>${u.lastName}, ${u.firstName} - ${u.email}</li>
            `,
        )}
      </ul>
    `;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('fetch-lit', FetchLit);
```

You can see this example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/fetch-lit

Comment: thanks for reply, lets say if i have multiple apis, is it possible to override the static content? like this please see the code part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285537/how-to-send-array-data-in-ajax-javascript

Comment: if this.users had one more object but override the data only for first object? Is it possible? If so please help

Comment: What do you mean "static content"? This solution overrides/overwrites the original content of 
 `this.users`. Merging is just vanilla JS. Look up `Array.concat()` or the spread operator (as in change `this.users = data.result` to `this.users = [...this.users, ...data.result]`).

Comment: if `this.users` had one more object, `fetch` should work for only users having `id: Jane` (override the data only for first object)? Is it possible? If so please help – Senthil 1 hour ago

Comment: Again, you're not in LitElement territory (or even JQuery). This is vanilla JS. Look at Array methods such as `find` and `split` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). It's in the language. Learn that first.

Comment: I do (if it helps ?) a quick reminder of async usage in Polymer... the interesting part is the challenge inside this link : https://blog.mlefree.com/2020/11/i-can-explain-js-async-scope.html